# Prove that a graph that has a Hamilton circuit

Tags: discrete-mathematics, hamiltonicity

How can I prove this:

> Let $G$ be a simple graph with with $n\geq3$ vertices and $m$ edges. If $m\geq \frac12 (n^2 - 3n +6),$ then $G$ has a Hamilton circuit.

Comment: That’s a lot of edges. The maximum number of edges on a graph with $n$ nodes is $\frac12n(n-1)= \frac12(n^2-3n+6)+n-3$

Comment: What have you tried? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes I know the maximum number, but I couldn't prove this If ≥12(2−3+6) then G has a Hamilton circuit.

Comment: @Aqua No. it did not solve my question